# Javascript custom button salesforce error

Tags: javascript, button, custom

I am trying to get the profile and username in JavaScript button but I am getting an error  when trying to click on the button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")} 

var currentuser = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();

if('{!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Approval_Status__c}' == 'Approved')
{
alert('{!$Profile.Name}')
if('{!$User.Id}' == '005E00000088akt')
{
 window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Id}&templateId=aH0V0000000CcVSKA0 ","_self"); 
}else if('{!$User.Id}' == '005E0000001noF2IAI')
{
 window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Id}&templateId=aH0V00000008PXg ","_self"); 
}else if('{!$Profile.Id}' == '00eE0000000eOCd')
{
window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid= 
{!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Id}&templateId=aH0V00000008PXl ","_self"); 
}
}else
{
window.alert("Please make sure Approval Status to be Approved");
}
```

When ever I add `else if('{!$Profile.Id}' == '00eE0000000eOCd')` condition , button is failing .Can you please let me know what I am missing

[image: Error when user clicks on button]

Comment: Can you update your question and provide the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Hi @John Towers : I updated the question with the error. Can you please let me know what I am missing in profile name

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that normal strings don't allow line breaks:

```
window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid= 
{!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Id}&templateId=aH0V00000008PXl ","_self");
```

This should fix your main problem:

```
window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!Contract_Approval_Form__c.Id}&templateId=aH0V00000008PXl ","_self");
```

---

As a side note, due to the possibility of script injection, you should prefer to use either JSENOCDE or do formula-based evaluation.

For example:

```
if({!ISPICKVAL(Contract_Approval_Form__c.Approval_Status__c,'Approved')})
```

And:

```
alert('{!JSENCODE($Profile.Name)}')
```

Note that the if statement simply renders as `if(true)` or `if(false)`, so no quotes are needed around the merge field.